# Server trusted on iOS 10 but not on any lower version of iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I am trying to connect to the server using authentication challenge and strangely I can successfully connect with iOS 10 but any attempt in iOS 9 or 8 simply fails.

In the code I call following method:

`-[NSURLSessionDataTask dataTaskWithRequest:completionBlock:]`

Strangely, when I call the following delegate method the server always return as trusted, no matter what iOS version I use:

`- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler`

This really bugs my head. I am on this stage unable to figure out where the problem lies.

This is how I understand the flow, and please correct me if I am wrong.
When I call `-[NSURLSessionDataTask dataTaskWithRequest:completionBlock:]` the authentication challenge is being run. The authentication challenge is simply asking server for the certificate and comparing with client certificate (that I store in the keychain). If all match this particular connection is marked as safe (trusted) with `NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential` parameter in the method `-[URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:]`. If there is no match the connection is rejected `NSURLSessionAuthChallengeRejectProtectionSpace`
After that the real connection (with request and response) will run. On this stage I get always error on iOS 8 and 9 but not on iOS 10. The error is as shown below:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “some.domain.eu” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo={
    NSErrorFailingURLKey = "https://some.domain.eu/something.svc";
    NSErrorFailingURLStringKey = "https://some.domain.eu/something.svc";
    NSLocalizedDescription = "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be \U201some.domain.eu\U201d which could put your confidential information at risk.";
    NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = "Would you like to connect to the server anyway?";
    NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey = "<SecTrustRef: 0x178308c0>";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1202 \"The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be \U201some.domain.eu\U201d which could put your confidential information at risk.\" UserInfo={\n    NSErrorFailingURLKey = \"https://some.domain.eu/something.svc\";\n    NSErrorFailingURLStringKey = \"https://some.domain.eu/something.svc\";\n    NSLocalizedDescription = \"The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be \\U201some.domain.eu\\U201d which could put your confidential information at risk.\";\n    NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = \"Would you like to connect to the server anyway?\";\n    \"_kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue\" = \"-9807\";\n    \"_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState\" = 1;\n    kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust = \"<SecTrustRef: 0x178308c0>\";\n}";
}
```

I thought the server was already marked as trusted, so why does it fail in real connection ? Did anything change in iOS 10 in respect to security that I should be aware ?

Thanks for your support

Comment: Post your authentication handler method.  I'm guessing you missed some important case—possibly for non-server-auth challenges.

Comment: BTW, unless there's a reason to reject valid certs, you should probably be requesting default handling if the cert doesn't match your trusted cert.